# SQLite3 Windows 11 - .databases command not printing a table, only a list

Tags: windows, sqlite, command-line

I'm trying to brush up on SQLite3 using some online tutorials, however the output I'm seeing on my own computer is different than those shown in the tutorials when I use the .databases command.

My output looks something like

```
sqlite> .databases
main: C:\sqlite\db\testDB.db r/w
test: C:\sqlite\db\testDB.db r/w
```

but the tutorials I'm looking at show the same output as

```
sqlite> .databases
seq name         file
--- ------------ ----------------------
0   main         C:\sqlite\db\testDB.db
2   test         C:\sqlite\db\testDB.db
```

I'm trying to get my output (the first code block) to look like those from the tutorials (the second code block). I've already tried

```
sqlite> .mode column
```

but it didn't do anything (I'm assuming it only affects tables). I'd really appreciate any guidance I could get on how to make this change in the output formatting.

I don't know if it's important, but I'm running SQLite3 version 3.37.0 from the Windows 11 command line (I have my SQLite3 directory as a PATH environment variable, and everything else seems to work fine).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `.databases` output was changed to no longer be columnar with SQLite version 3.16.0, released on 2017-01-02, and further modified with 3.34.0 on 2020-12-01.  There is no option to revert this change.

Comment: @AnonCoward thank you for this information, I thought something might've been wrong with one of my install files. Glad to know it's just a cosmetic update.